# Model ensembling when classifiers work with different classification thresholds

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning, threshold

I have a 2-class classification problem at hand and trained three classifiers to tackle this task. In doing so, I determined for each classifier the optimal classification threshold. For example, classifier1 might predict class 1 for values > O.5 while classifier2 already predicts class 1 for values > 0.4. Of course I could easily obtain a majority vote from these different models but I would like to somehow take into account how certain each vote is. Since I have different thresholds, I cannot simply take the average value and compare it to a threshold. What could be possible measures?

Comment: Why not use each model's risk estimate as a feature in a new model?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment.
If you have only three classifiers, you can be precise on what you want. E.g. If one of the classifiers has above 0.95 you would want the answer to be true, even though the other classifiers are less than 0.5. Just change the ensemble that will return true if any of the predictions are above 0.95, otherwise return regular ensemble function.